# Is the drawing after "The wind converses with the grove" part of the poem?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, taras-shevchenko, the-complete-kobzar

Immediately after the poem *The wind converses with the grove*, *The Complete Kobzar* (translated by Peter Fedynsky) has a drawing (possibly charcoal or pencil, but I'm not sure) merely entitled *Forest's Edge, 1845-47*. With apologies for the slightly poor picture:

[image]

I'm somewhat confused by this, though. I wasn't able to find any more details on the background of this (such as who drew it). Given that Taras Shevchenko was also an artist, it's entirely possible that he did it, but it's not clearly identified. Also, was it intended to be part of the poem, or did the translator just happen to include it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this work appears to be by Taras Shevchenko. The Ukranian Wikipedia site helpfully has a page for [List of paintings and drawings by Taras Shevchenko](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D1%96_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0), which gives the title of the [work](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D1%96_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0#/media/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Taras_Shevchenko_painting_0131.jpg) as Узлісся (which could indeed translate as "Forest's edge"), notes that it is a pencil drawing with watercolor made on paper, and dates it to between 1845 and 1847.

Further details are available from [Taras Shevchenko, A complete collection of works in ten volumes](http://litopys.org.ua/shevchenko/shev7131.htm), which corroborates the above information from Wikipedia, and further notes that:

> In terms of execution, the drawing is close to similar works of
> Shevchenko 1845–1847. It dates back to Shevchenko's stay in Ukraine
> in 1845–1847.

The original 1874 version of Kobzar seems not to contain any pictures (except for a portrait of Shevchenko on the frontispiece), and so it is probable that the artwork was just included as an illustration for the modern translated version.